# Use yield inside of setTimeOut in redux saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux-saga

In my React project I have the following code:

```js
export function* onDisplayAlert({ payload }: any) {
  payload.id = getUniqueID();
  yield put(setAlert(payload));

  yield setTimeout(() => {
    yield put(removeAlert(payload.id));
  }, 3000);
}
```

What I want to do here is use `yield` inside `setTimeOut` callback.

```js
yield put(removeAlert(payload.id));
```

But the way I have written this doesn't work, because the arrow function callback is not a generator function, so I can't use yield inside it. How can I use yield inside `setTimeOut`?

Comment: please explain more we did not get your point

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How do you use `onDisplayAlert`?

Comment: Is the answer of @alex2007v somehow do not suit you?

Answer (score 11):

this is what you need

```
export function* onDisplayAlert({ payload }: any) {
  payload.id = getUniqueID();
  yield put(setAlert(payload));
  yield delay(3000);
  yield put(removeAlert(payload.id));
}
```

Comment: just adding that the `delay` function is imported from `redux-saga/effects`. See here for more https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#delayms-val